# Insert trigger to update second table

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I am trying to write an insert trigger that performs the following

I have a member table T1(ID, score, sex) and a matching table T2(ID1,ID2,Dscore). These two tables are initially empty. When an insert is made on T1, a trigger will fire such that it will insert information into table T2 depending on the row that was inserted in T1. If the insert on T1 is the first row then nothing will be inserted into T2. If a subsequent row is inserted into T1 then the difference in scores (absolute value) between the inserted row and any previously rows in T1 will be inserted in T2 provided it is of different sex (male=1 and female=0).Below are a few examples

insert into member values(1,5,1)

```
ID         score       sex
 1            5           1
```

First row so no action on table T2

```
ID1        ID2        Dscore
```

insert into member values(2,6,0)

```
 ID         score       sex
    1           5               1
    2           6               0

Second row and opposite sex type, so insert all the possible differences
ID1        ID2        Dscore
2            1             1
```

insert into member values(3,7,1)

```
ID         score       sex
    1           5           1
    2           6           0
    3           7           1


ID1        ID2        Dscore
    2             1          1
    3             2          1
```

I am stuck on the part where I can insert ID2 and Dscore into t2. This is what I've written so far

```
   CREATE TRIGGER MEMBER_INSERT_TRI
ON Employee.Dbo.T_1 
After INSERT AS 
Declare @ID int 
Select @ID = (Select ID from inserted)
IF @ID > 1
Begin 
Declare @ID2 as int 
Set @ID2 = @ID2 +1
Insert into Employee.dbo.T_2 
(
    ID1,
    ID2,
    Score
)

Select 
ID,
@ID2,
Score
From 
    Inserted
END
```

Thank you

Comment: Thanks. I've done that. This is for sql server

Answer (score 0):

You can use INSERTED view to get inserted/updated row in trigger, If you are talking about MS SQL Server. Then you can call a stored procedure to make it happen.